# Add arbitrary audio clips to existing video with ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

(Edit: See below for fixed version)

I'm building an app to create videos and animations. Users can add text and video elements. I've built a renderer that generates frames and creates a video with ffmpeg, but now I'd like to include audio from video clips users have added.

For example, a user might embed a video (subclip.mp4) 10 seconds into their animation. They can also trim the video so it starts at second 5 of subclip.mp4 and ends at second 10.

So I need to add audio:

- The audio is coming from a video (subclip.mp4)
- The audio is taken from 5s-10s in subclip.mp4
- The audio starts at 10s (and plays for 5s) in the generated video.

I was hoping I could use something like:

```
ffmpeg -i main-video.mp4 -i subclip.mp4 \
  -filter_complex "[1:a]atrim=5:10;[1:a]adelay=5000"
  ...
```

Obviously, that doesn't work. The trim seems to do the right thing, but I can't seem to place it at the right point in the video. I've also played with asetpts but it didn't seem to do anything.

Last, I'd like to merge all of the audio into a single track. Played around with concat and map to merge with no luck as well.

**Edit**

Got it working. Here's the working command. It includes a video, a full background audio track (1.mp3) and an audio overlay (2.mp4). The overlay is 3.3 seconds and starts at 3.15s into the video:

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i video.mp4 -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp4 \
  -filter_complex \
  "[1:a]atrim=0:11.83,apad=whole_dur=11.83[a1];[2:a]atrim=0:3.3382,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,adelay=3150.0|3150.0,apad[a2];[a1][a2]amerge[a]" \
  -map [a] -map v:0 out.mp4
```

The command is generated with code, so there's probably some superfluous stuff in there.

Comment: Post your full command attempt.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for not providing that before. Managed to get it working, so I updated my post with a working command :)

Comment: Since you found a working command you can add it as an answer to your question. Adding the answer inside the question is not as good.

Comment: Done! Thanks for the tip. Been reading answers here for years, but this is my first post.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Here's the working command. It includes a video, a full background audio track (1.mp3) and an audio overlay (2.mp4). The overlay is 3.3 seconds and starts at 3.15s into the video:

```
# Note: -f concat isn't necessary here. I'm generating the video with threads so I actually pass in a list of videos.
ffmpeg -y -f concat -i video.mp4 -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp4 \
  -filter_complex \
  "[1:a]atrim=0:11.83,apad=whole_dur=11.83[a1];[2:a]atrim=0:3.3382,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS,adelay=3150.0|3150.0,apad[a2];[a1][a2]amerge[a]" \
  -map [a] -map v:0 out.mp4
```

The command is generated with code, so there's probably some superfluous stuff in there.